# CSS transition not working in chrome but works in safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition

Link to site: http://178.159.11.114/~experiments/services/

Note transition is on images to the right..

I've read various posts and thought the -webkit- would fix this but to no avail..

On firefox it 'eases' in with 'fade-in' like style whereas on chrome it's like the flick of a switch.. on or off..

CSS

```
.masonryImage, .columnContainer img, .rev_slider { /* GRAYSCALE OPTION  */

    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5) contrast(0.75) grayscale(0.9) !important;
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.5) contrast(0.75) grayscale(0.9) !important;
    filter: brightness(0.5) contrast(0.75) grayscale(0.9) !important;

    transition: -webkit-filter all 0.5s ease !important, transition all 0.5s ease !important; /* fix? */ 
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}

.masonryImage:hover, .columnContainer img:hover, .rev_slider:hover { 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0) contrast(1) !important;
    filter: none !important;


    transition: -webkit-filter all 0.5s ease !important, transition all 0.5s ease !important; /* fix? */ 
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}
```

Comment: its working fine in my crome

Comment: Ahh I've re-worded my question.. it's working per say.. but on the different browsers the transition behaves differently.. I'm looking to apply the firefox 'ease' into chrome..